# iframe embed with variable as src in pug is not working

Tags: node.js, express, pug, ejs

This is the code that was working with ejs:

```
<iframe width="660" height="371" src="<%= revive.reviveVideo %>"></iframe>
```

What is the equivalent of this in pug? Tried this but it did not work:

```
iframe(width='660', height='371', src='#{revive.reviveVideo}')
```

If I change the variable to the actual path it works just fine... It's an issue with the syntax of the variable...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I finally found it:

```
iframe(width='660', height='371', src=revive.reviveVideo)
```

is the correct new syntax for pug